# How to get date difference in SQL Server and return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How to get day difference from when the user registered to current date? I have this scenario:

I have some fixed value in master table like `[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42 .....]`
and suppose

1. day difference is greater or equal than 1 and less than 6 then It should be return 1.
2. day difference is greater than 6 and less than 12 then it should return 2 and so on.
3. day difference is greater than 12 and less than 18 then return 3.
4. day difference is greater than 18 and less than 24 then return 4.
   .
   .
   .

And so on.
I don't want to use case statements because values in master table can not be fix but value pattern will be fix. table value pattern is like that:
common difference between two consecutive values is 6 i.e.

```
if n=0 then 
   n+1 = (0 + 6) => 6
```

Thanks

```
declare @day int;
declare @regdate datetime = '2019-12-09 19:24:19.623';
declare @currentDate datetime = GETDATE();
SET @day = (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @regdate, @currentDate) % 6  FROM tblMembers  WHERE Id = 1)
PRINT @day
```

Comment: What about a day difference = 6?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for integer division, not modulo. This is the default behavior in SQL Server when both arguments are integers, so, since `DATEDIFF` returns an integer, this should do it:

```
1 + DATEDIFF(day, @regdate, @currentDate) / 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's approach you can build your solution on:

```
declare @masterTable table (id int, col int);
insert into @masterTable values
(1,0) ,
(2,6) ,
(3,12),
(4,18),
(5,24),
(6,30),
(7,36),
(8,42),
(9,48);

-- test data
declare @day int;
declare @regdate datetime = '2019-12-09 19:24:19.623';
declare @currentDate datetime = GETDATE();
select @day = datediff(day, @regdate, @currentDate)

;with cte as (
    select id,
           col lowerBound,
           -- here we need to provide some fallback value for last record
           coalesce(lead(col) over (order by id), 1000) upperBound
    from @masterTable
)

select id from (values (@day)) [day]([cnt])
join cte on [day].[cnt] between cte.lowerBound and cte.upperBound
```